# Handling cases when a parameter is passed/not passed and nil

Tags: elixir

In my Phoenix/Elixir application I have this:

```
def new(conn, %{"var1" => var1}) do
  # ......
```

When a parameter "var1" isn't passed in the URL or when it's nil, it throws an exception. How can I fix that? The thing is that I want to handle 3 cases: it's not passed, it's passed but nil or has no value `&var1="` and when it's passed normally with a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you want to handle three different cases, you should handle three different cases. One might do this using pattern matching in function clauses:

```
def new(conn, %{"var1" => nil}) do
  IO.puts "nil passed"
end
def new(conn, %{"var1" => var1}) do
  IO.puts "var1 passed: #{inspect(var1)}"
end
def new(conn, %{} = _params) do
  IO.puts "var1 NOT passed"
end
```

Please note, that the order of clauses matters, since pattern matching is done in natural order, from top to bottom, as function declarations appear.

---

Another way round would be to just receive `params` and check whether it contains `var1`:

```
def new(conn, %{} = params) do
  if Map.has_key?(params, "var1") do
    %{"var1" => var1} = params
    IO.puts "var1 passed: #{inspect(var1)}"
  else
    IO.puts "var1 omitted"
  end
end
```

---

*Sidenote:* your original code won’t throw an exception if `var1` *is* passed, but *is* `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem recently. The above version works if it's only var1 as the key, as soon as you have multiple keys it will get tricky.

I fixed by normalizing the hash with default values.

```
@default_params %{"var1" => nil}

def new(conn, params) do
  params |> normalize |> handle
end

defp normalize(params) do
 @default_params |> Map.merge(params)
end
defp handle(%{"var1" => var1}) do
  IO.puts "var1 passed: #{inspect(var1)}"
end
defp handle(%{"var1" => nil}) do
  IO.puts "var1 NOT passed"
end
```